# 動く背景がクリックすると表示され、別のものをクリックするとそちらに動く背景が移るメニューを作りたい

Tags: html, jquery, css

クリックしてアクティブにしたリンクの背景にだけ、ふわふわと動く背景画像を出現させたいです。
cssだけでできないかと調べてlabelを試して失敗し、jqueryでクラスを付け替えることを試しましたがうまくいきません。

コードは以下

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>タイトル</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="flex_" id="nav_">
            <li><a href="#">top</a></li>
            <li><a href="#one">関連記事</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two">みなさんのメッセージ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="one">
        <p>ここはoneだよ</p>
    </section>
    <section id="two">
        <p>ここはtwoだよ</p>
    </section>
    <script>
        var linkList = $('#nav li');
//リストをクリックした時の処理
linkList.on('click', function () {
    //リンクのclass設定をリセット
    linkList.removeClass('huwahuwa');
    //クリックしたリストにcurrentのclassを追加
    $(this).addClass('huwahuwa');
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>

@charset "utf-8";

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative ;
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: 0.3s;
      -o-transition: 0.3s;
      -ms-transition: 0.3s;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }

nav{
    height:90px;
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.flex_{
    max-width: 1200px;
    width:40%;
    margin:0 0 0 60%;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

@media(max-width: 959px){
    body{
        width:100%;
    }
    .flex_{
        width:95%;
        margin:0  auto;
    }
}

.flex_ a{
    display: block;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:15px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.huwahuwa{
    animation:huwahuwa 3s infinite ease-in-out .8s alternate;
    background:url(icon.png) no-repeat center center / 60px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    z-index:-99;
}

@keyframes huwahuwa {
    0%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(-7deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform:translate(0,-7px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(7deg);
    }
}

.huwahuwa2{
    animation:huwahuwa 2.7s infinite ease-in-out .65s alternate;
    background:url(icon.png) no-repeat center center / 60px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    z-index:-99;
}

@keyframes huwahuwa2 {
    0%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(-7deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform:translate(0,-7px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(7deg);
    }
}

.flex_ a:hover{
    opacity:0.6;
    transition: .6s;
}

#one,#two,#three{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
#one{
    margin-top:80px;
    background:pink;
    z-index:-100;
}
#two{
    background:skyblue;
    z-index:-100;
}
#three{
    background:green;
    z-index:-100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

「ふわふわと動く背景画像」とは一体どういうものか
出来上がりのイメージがあいまいでよくわかりませんでした。

ただjQueryが動かないのは"nav_"になっているからかなと思います。
navにすれば正しく動くと思います。

```js
var linkList = $('#nav li');
//リストをクリックした時の処理
linkList.on('click', function () {
    //リンクのclass設定をリセット
    $("section").removeClass('huwahuwa');
    $(this).addClass('huwahuwa');
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative ;
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: 0.3s;
      -o-transition: 0.3s;
      -ms-transition: 0.3s;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }

nav{
    height:90px;
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.flex_{
    max-width: 1200px;
    width:40%;
    margin:0 0 0 60%;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

@media(max-width: 959px){
    body{
        width:100%;
    }
    .flex_{
        width:95%;
        margin:0  auto;
    }
}

.flex_ a{
    display: block;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:15px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.huwahuwa{
    animation:huwahuwa 3s infinite ease-in-out .8s alternate;
    background:url(icon.png) no-repeat center center / 60px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    z-index:-99;
}

@keyframes huwahuwa {
    0%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(-7deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform:translate(0,-7px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(7deg);
    }
}

.huwahuwa2{
    animation:huwahuwa 2.7s infinite ease-in-out .65s alternate;
    background:url(icon.png) no-repeat center center / 60px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    z-index:-99;
}

@keyframes huwahuwa2 {
    0%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(-7deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform:translate(0,-7px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:translate(0,0) rotate(7deg);
    }
}

.flex_ a:hover{
    opacity:0.6;
    transition: .6s;
}

#one,#two,#three{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}
#one{
    margin-top:80px;
    background:pink;
    z-index:-100;
}
#two{
    background:skyblue;
    z-index:-100;
}
#three{
    background:green;
    z-index:-100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <ul class="flex_" id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">top</a></li>
            <li><a href="#one">関連記事</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two">みなさんのメッセージ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="one">
        <p>ここはoneだよ</p>
    </section>
    <section id="two">
        <p>ここはtwoだよ</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。無事に動きました！ただ文字は動かしたくないのでliじゃないところにクラスをつけないといけないようです。linklistのようなものをliの直下にあるdivにつけるときのセレクタは何がいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答を追記しておきました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます！ええと、文字の背後の画像が現れて、画像だけゆらゆらと動くのを作りたかったんです。liの直下に空のdivを新しく作ってhuwahuwaがaddClassで入るブロックを作ればいいのでしょうか？という質問でした。わかりづらくてすみません。